# PHP-Slim-Restful API 404 Page Not Found

Tags: .htaccess, rest

Each time I connect to my api, I get an 404 error.

I think it is problem with my httpd.conf.

My api is calling /api/signup

I have a .htaccess into my api folder:

```
RewriteEngine On

#RewriteBase /api/

Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Headers "origin, x-requested-with, content-type"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Methods "PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS"

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
```

my httpd.conf is as follow:

```
ServerRoot "/etc/httpd"

Listen 80

Include conf.modules.d/*.conf


User apache
Group apache

ServerAdmin root@localhost

<Directory />
    AllowOverride none
    Require all denied
</Directory>

DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"

<Directory "/var/www">
    AllowOverride All

    Require all granted
</Directory>


<Directory "/var/www/html">

    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks

    AllowOverride All

    Allow from all

    Require all granted
</Directory>

<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.html
</IfModule>

<Files ".ht*">
    Require all denied
</Files>

ErrorLog "logs/error_log"

LogLevel warn

<IfModule log_config_module>

    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common

    <IfModule logio_module>

      LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" %I %O" combinedio
    </IfModule>

    CustomLog "logs/access_log" combined
</IfModule>

<IfModule alias_module>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "/var/www/cgi-bin/"

</IfModule>

<Directory "/var/www/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<IfModule mime_module>

    TypesConfig /etc/mime.types

    AddType application/x-compress .Z
    AddType application/x-gzip .gz .tgz

    AddType text/html .shtml
    AddOutputFilter INCLUDES .shtml
</IfModule>

AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

<IfModule mime_magic_module>

    MIMEMagicFile conf/magic
</IfModule>

EnableSendfile on

IncludeOptional conf.d/*.conf
```

When I am calling other files it is not returning 404 so I guess it is problem with my httpd.conf file but I can not spot the problem.

Any idea?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem..

I did before the change into my httpd.conf like that:

```
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks

    AllowOverride All

    Allow from all

    Require all granted
```

before it was not ALL.

the problem was: I did not restart apache. After a restart it works